# Inducitve Proximity Sensor - Safety Gate Latch Codes?

Tags: proximity-sensor, inductive

If I am using an inductive proximity sensors as a safety gate latch, what codes and standards do I need to abide by?

Some safety sensors I research have:
 - Category 3 (EN ISO 13849)
 - Safety integrity level (SIL2, SILCL2)
 - EN ISO 14119

How do I figure out for a given application, what safety integrity level, category, performance level..etc I require for my application?

Edit: We are trying to follow NFPA70, 33, and CSA

Comment: A safety gate on what?

Comment: It will be mounted to a door that enters the work area, when the metal door opens the inductive proximity sensor will trigger.

Answer (score 0):

> If I am using an inductive proximity sensors as a **safety gate latch** ...
>
> ... when the metal door opens **the inductive proximity sensor will trigger.**

I'm concerned that you may not understand the potential failure modes.

> Safety integrity level (SIL) is defined as a relative level of risk-reduction provided by a safety function, or to specify a target level of risk reduction. In simple terms, SIL is a measurement of performance required for a safety instrumented function (SIF). Source: [Safety integrity level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_integrity_level).

You need to perform a risk analysis based on

- Severity of possible injury.
- Frequency of exposure.
- Likelihood of avoidance.

That will determine the SIL required.

In general, an inductive proximity switch would not be suitable. You can't predict its failure mode - open-circuit or short-circuit and therefore you can't guarantee that it will switch off the hazard when "triggered" - whatever that means.

Instead, the SIL will require that the switch output turns off when the guard is opened - either by forced disconnection of the switch contacts or by some other means. If there is a risk of permanent or "non-reversible" injury or death the system will require redundant or dual-channel safety with a safety controller that will guarantee that a fault on one channel is detected and will not reset until the fault is cleared.

Your question and comments suggest that you are going to use a prox switch to detect *opening* of the gate. Instead your safety must prove that the safety gate is *closed* before energising the circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: Thanks for the response!

By "triggered" I was referring to a rising edge. The proximity sensor is a N.O switch, meaning when the gate is detected by the switch the circuit will close, indicating to the safety relays that we are in a safe state. This will also be fail-safe in the event of power loss. 

However, my question was in regards to the codes and standards and I think you gave me a place to start. I was more looking for a required working range of inductive sensors (ie the door can only open <5mm before the door is no longer detected) or respond in < X ms.

Comment: But what happens when the output transistor fails short-circuit? If you have a part in mind then post a datasheet link.